# Position of button not changing

Tags: html, css

I developed a python back-end and is trying to design a html and javascript front end for my app. I am new to HTML.

The code is provided below

```css
        html{
            font:normal 14px/1.5 Courier New;
        }
        h1{
            margin: 7rem;
            margin-top: 8rem;
        }
        form{
            margin: 3rem;
            width: 800px;
        }
        .form-IFS_DataLocation{
            font-size: 1rem;
            width: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 400px

         }
        .form-IFS_DataLocation button{
            font-size: 0.7rem;
            border: none;
            padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
            color: white;
            background-color: cornflowerblue;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .form-PDF_Location{
            font-size: 1rem;
            width: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .form-PDF_Location button{
            font-size: 0.7rem;
            border: none;
            padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
            color: white;
            background-color: cornflowerblue;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .form-Output_Location{
            font-size: 1rem;
            width: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
       .form-Output_Location button{
           font-size: 0.7rem;
           border: none;
           padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
           color: white;
           background-color: cornflowerblue;
           cursor: pointer;
       }
       .form-HighLight{
          font-size: 1rem;
          width: 200px;
          position: absolute;
          margin-top: 10px;

       }
      .form-Highlight button{
          font-size: 0.7rem;
          border: none;
          padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
          color: white;
          background-color: cornflowerblue;
          cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Working with HTML Forms</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <h1><center>Test<center></h1>

    <form id="form-user" action="#" method="post">

    <div class="form-IFS_DataLocation">
        <button id="button1">Shop Order</button>
    <div>

    <div class="form-PDF_Location">
        <button id="button2">PDF Drawings</button>
    <div>

    <div class="form-Output_Location">
        <button id="button3">Output</button>
    <div>

    <div class="form-Highlight">
        <button id="button4">Execute</button>
    <div>

    </form>

    <script src="./test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the css portion of the code for the highlight button (ID: button4), changing the `margin-top` property is having no effect. From what I understand, it should move the button `10px` below the button above.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through that step by step.

1. The html is invalid. You have to close all tags in html (with a few exception which you'll find on google). the `div` and `center` is not closed. If you use an IDE like webstorm or eclipse or ... (many many...) they'll show your mistakes immanently. Think of DIV's in your html as wrappers, or boxes which enclose whatever that is inside of them:

```html
    <!-- close the center tag: -->
    <h1><center>Test</center></h1>

    <!-- here! close the div tag: -->
    <div class="form-IFS_DataLocation">
        <button id="button1">Shop Order</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Just the same for rest of div blocks... -->
```

2. You are making your life a lot harder than it needs to be. When writing CSS, you shouldn't style every element in your html individually. Instead, in CSS you would say: `I want all my buttons to be cornflowerblue, with text size of .7 rem` and then, in HTML, you just tag those elements that should behave like a button. Your wish will be applied to them:

```css
/* state your wish, and name your wish such as .btn */
.btn { background-color: cornflowerblue;  font-size: .7 rem; }

/* another wish, about danger elemets */
.danger { color: red; }
```

And in html:

```html
<!-- which wishes to apply here? you can combine -->
<!-- this is both "button" and "dangerous" -->
<div class="btn danger">BURN THE KITTENS</div>

<!-- this is just a "button" -->
<div class="btn">Feed the kittens</div>
```

3. Don't use `absolute` in css unless necessary. Which in this case is not! I believe you want your buttons on the left side of screen. Think of different screen sizes, mobile screen, TV, event pages being printed on paper. Absolute will make your life hell. Also you can see the margin is not working on an absolute element. If you want your buttons always on the left side of screen make their parent div fixed.
4. *Sometimes* it's a good idea to stack related things (like buttons) together (wrapping them in a div). But don't over do it.

So finally:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Working with HTML Forms</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    <center>Test</center>
  </h1>

  <form id="form-user" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="app-buttons">
      <div class="form-IFS_DataLocation form-element">
        <button id="button1">Shop Order</button>
      </div>

      <div class="form-PDF_Location form-element">
        <button id="button2">PDF Drawings</button>
      </div>

      <div class="form-Output_Location form-element">
        <button id="button3">Output</button>
      </div>

      <div class="form-Highlight form-element">
        <button id="button4">Execute</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <script src="./test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And:

```
html { font: normal 14px/1.5 Courier New; }
h1 {  margin: 7rem;  margin-top: 8rem; }
form {  margin: 3rem;  width: 800px; }

/* Style all the buttons in one go */
button {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.form-element {
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;  
}
```

Run the example here: https://codepen.io/hkoosha/pen/XWWYvxd

Final note: you are wrapping your `button` in another `div` with class `form-IFS_...`. This could be unnecessary and you can simply use the `button` element only. Your mileage may vary though.

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-top property to button tag, and remove all other margin-top property from, other classes.

```
#form-user button{
      margin-top:10px;
  }
```